# Find ($A + x B)^{-1}$ where $A$ and $B$ are $N \times N$ matrices, and $x$ is a scalar. $A^{-1}$ and $B^{-1}$ are known but $x$ is variable.

Tags: inverse, matrix-equations

How does a change in the scalar $x$ affect the inverse $(A + xB)^{-1}$? $A$ and $B$ are both arbitrarily sized matrices of $N \times N$ with a known inverse. In this problem, $A^{-1}$ and $B^{-1}$ are known.

-edit
-**motivation**
I am trying to implement a control algorithm on an embedded system. The x represents the change in the time variable used to plan the trajectory. To save time, I am precomputing this matrix but still want to change my prediction horizon by varying my delta t. This x is typically less than 1 but the matrix B can become bigger than that

Comment: Welcome to mse ^_^. What are you looking for? What kind of information would you like? Are we thinking about $x$ as a "small" scalar in some sense, for instance? Currently it's hard to know how to answer this because it's not clear what you want to know about $(A + xB)^{-1}$.

Comment: The formulas found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity#Inverse_of_a_sum) may be useful.

Comment: I am trying to implement a control algorithm on an embedded system.  The x represents the change in the time variable used to plan the trajectory.  To save time, I am precomputing this matrix but still want to change my prediction horizon by varying my delta t.  This x is typically less than 1 but the matrix B can become bigger than that.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming $A^{-1}$ exists, $(A+xB)^{-1} = A^{-1} (I + x B A^{-1})^{-1}$ exists whenever $-1/x$ is not an eigenvalue of $BA^{-1}$.  Its matrix elements are rational functions of the complex variable $x$; at their poles, $-1/x$ is an eigenvalue of $BA^{-1}$.